# SSL Certificates and adding in CA root certificates

Tags: ssl, ansible, ssl-certificate, jks, aries

I am trying to automate the creations of jks certs via ansible for linux servers.

i am able to generate a private key, CSR however when creating the server certificate i am using the ansible openssl_certificate module and creating it as selfsigned. Then create the .jks keystore.

my company uses 'Microsolf Activie directory services - Aries' to sign the certs.

my question is if i add the Ariesroot cert to the jks keystore will that work in trusting any certs that have been trusted by that CA?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it looks like adding the root cert to the cert will indeed allow all certs that have been signed by that CA access